# Building irods-rest with Maven 3

Tags: maven, ubuntu, maven-3

I'm trying to install irods-rest on Ubuntu 14.04. This are the steps that I have follow untill now:

Maven 3 Installation

- `sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3`
- `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install maven3`

Irods-Rest Installation

- `git clone https://github.com/DICE-UNC/irods-rest.git`
- `cd irods-rest/`
- `mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

but I get this error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project irods-rest: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8`

Can somebody help me?

EDIT:
I solved this issue after installing java 8 (before I had java 7)

Comment: Don't use OS dependent Maven installations better download from download page...Furthermore you have installed the wrong JDK to compile the package.

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm a beginner in this sort of stuff. Can you explain me for example how can I know what is my actual JDK and how can I know what is the correct version?